# An error occurred while trying to obtain a WOPI token

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph Explorer I can easily explore the possibilities of the graph api. Based on the documentation, I composed the following url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/Map.xlsx/workbook/worksheets

unfortunately this gives an error response:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "An error occurred while trying to obtain a WOPI token.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "d0fce37f-0c53-44bd-abc8-53a83a5bb9e8",
        "date": "2016-07-13T11:33:15",
        "status": 404,
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found."
    }
}
```

Figured this might be a shortcoming to the api explorer, so created a sample app (MVC) to test this, but got the same error message. I can't find any documentation about this message.
The Excel part of the api is still in beta, so am I doing anything wrong or is it simply the api that still in development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the file exists?  I remember getting a similar message a few days ago when I had mistyped the name of the file (we have a pending bug to make the error message reflect the actual error)

**Update**:  Note that if you're using file name rather than ID, it's a bit of a special syntax (note the :/'s):

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/root:/MyFile.xlsx:/workbook/tables/transactionstable/
```

Comment: Hmm guess that must be it. Using the id instead of the filename I do get a valid response. Don't get it fixed using the filename though..

Comment: Ah that's probably it. Will try it tomorrow

Comment: Thanks, got it to work now. Wonder if I can use graph api to access Excel files from sharepoint teamsite. That would be my next step.